# Equivalent of max.word parameter for WordCloud2 in R

Tags: r, word-cloud

I am trying to build a wordcloud using `Wordcloud2` in `R` in order to take advantage of Shiny. 
One very important thing that I must do is maintain a fixed maximum number of words to represent in the wordcloud (for instance 150). Therefore, regardless of the number of words that are available I only want to visualize a maximum of 150 words in the cloud.
In `Wordcloud`, this parameter `max.words=` is available. However, I am having trouble finding something equivalent for `Wordcloud2` that allows me to add this parameter. I have done a lot of research regarding this and cannot seem to find it. My code for `Wordcloud2` is very simple

```
mr = table(data, header=TRUE)
wordcloud2(mr, color = ifelse(mr[, 3] > 0, 'green', 'red'), fontWeight = "bold")
```

Is there any parameter that I can add such as `max.words=` (available in `Wordcloud`)to guarantee that no more that X words appear in my cloud?

My data is 3 columns, such as:

```
              WORD VALUE SENT
1         topnotch     1    1
2             good     2    1
3             nice     11    0
4         inspired     14    0
5        beautiful     21    0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see an argument that you can pass to accomplish that. I would just subset the data set before passing it to the wordcloud, like:

```
data <- data[order(data$Value, decreasing = TRUE), ]
pass_to_wordcloud <- data[1:150, ] #or set 150 to whatever
```